# GCC дефолтный static на всё что не extern

Tags: c, gcc, static

Возможно ли каким-нибудь волшебным, не иначе, образом автоматически приводить все определения переменных/функций/... статичными для данного файла? Что бы что-то типа этого:

```
extern int a;
int b;

int a=13;
b=66;
```

превращалось в это:

```
extern int a;
static int b;

int a=13;
b=66;
```

Comment: Конфликт имен обнаружился? Можно попробовать погрузить файл в namespace, но это уже не Си, а С++.

Comment: Не, конфликтов нету. Просто хочется автоматом разграничивать пространства имен модулей проекта, и все в рамках Си (GCC or Clang).
-fvisibility смотрел, но это, кажись, только динамичной линковки работает.

Comment: Если конфликтов имен нет, то и заморачиваться с разграничением пространств имен не стоит. Линкуйтесь как есть и вперед.

Comment: Если где-то в хедере у вас переменная объявлена `extra`, а в `.c` коде просто имя , то автоматом проставленная `static` приведёт к большой проблеме. Стандарт : `If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external
linkage, the behavior is undefined.`

Comment: Оо, это очень интересно. Благодарю!